# how to find the last character position of a line in word using interop using c#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, interop, office-interop

how to find the last character position of a line in word using interop. Using C# code , how to find last position of line .

Comment: This makes no sense on several levels... Can you expand?

Comment: Pls answer for my doubt. thanks in adavance.           I have a word document consisting of one paragraph , which contains 5 lines.   I want to know get the position of last character of the first line of paragraph.   For example- The first line is ...... This is stackoverflow account...... I want to get the position of the letter "w".

Comment: ^above makes no sense too

Comment: Pls answer for my doubt. thanks in adavance.           I have a word document consisting of one paragraph , which contains 5 lines.   I want to know get the position of last character of the first line of paragraph.   For example- The first line is ...... This is stackoverflow account...... I want to get the position of the letter "t".

Answer (score 2):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application application = new Application();
        Document document = application.Documents.Open("D:\\test.doc");

        if (document.Paragraphs.Count > 0)
        {
            var paragraph = document.Paragraphs.First;
            var lastCharPos = paragraph.Range.Sentences.First.End-1;
            Console.WriteLine(lastCharPos);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! It works wonderful.....  also it would  be helpful if u tell me the code for retrieving the found position's character.    Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! It works wonderful..... also it would be helpful if u tell me the code for retrieving the found position's character. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you can do that like this `paragraph.Range.Text[lastCharPos-1]`